Salesforce Set Password in Bulk DML Error
I have 500 user accounts stored in a list.
I want to set their password to a specific string. I have code that is running fine but it generates a DML error when the list becomes larger than 150. I need to get around this error and set the passwords for all 500 users in one go. Any help will be appreciated.
I have tried this code and it works fine till user 151.
List<User> userList = [SELECT Id from User WHERE IsActive = true];
for(User usr : userList) {
    System.setPassword(usr.Id, 'xxxxxxxx');
    System.debug('DONE: ' + usr.Id);
}


setPassword is special, consumes 1 DML statement out of limit of 150 and can be called only 1 user at a time.
You can bulk reset passwords for all users in the org from Setup UI (but this will send pass reset emails, it won't set the passwords). Or cut your script into 4 chunks, 150 users at a time.
Try something like this:
Integer cutoff = Limits.getLimitDMLStatements(); // 150
Integer offset = 0;

List<User> userList = [SELECT Id, Name
FROM User
WHERE IsActive = true AND Name NOT IN ('Automated Process', 'System')
ORDER BY Id ASC
LIMIT :cutoff
OFFSET :offset];
for(User usr : userList) {
    System.debug(usr);
    System.setPassword(usr.Id, 'abcd1234!');
}
System.debug('Done, increase the "offset" by ' + cutoff + ' and rerun');
Assert.fail('all good, just trying it out');

If this works OK, "just" throws that last exception - you can remore this line and run it for real.
There may be other system users that will refuse to change the password (Site/Community guest users if you have any; users with Single Sign-On enabled), I'd recommend experimenting in a sandbox first. You could filter them out in the query or wrap the setPassword in a try-catch.
You can find more info about OFFSET here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm

Edit: slightly different trick for > 2000 users. Write down the Id of the last processed user, then modify the query for the next run.
So the first execution would have
SELECT Id, Name
FROM User
WHERE IsActive = true AND Name NOT IN ('Automated Process', 'System')
ORDER BY Id ASC
LIMIT 150

And the next ones would be
SELECT Id, Name
FROM User
WHERE IsActive = true AND Name NOT IN ('Automated Process', 'System') 
    AND Id > '005...'
ORDER BY Id ASC
LIMIT 150


Thank you for your help. Cutting the script into chunks and using OFFEST worked. I removed the last line,because it threw me an exception. Suggesting the offset keyword and providing its doc link was really helpful. Thanks again

Followup question. Actually, I have 3000 testusers that I need to set the pwd for. I just learnt (from the OFFSET help link) that  setting the OFFSET limit is 2000, anything higher and it will give an error. Now, how do I set the pwd for the last 1000 testusers?

Updated the answer. Since you already processed 2K... you could use your query to figure out who's the 2000th or view Setup -> Setup Audit Trail to inspect who had the pass set last

You know what, I may have been overthinking it and sent you down a rabbit hole... Check  if LastPasswordChangeDate field changes on user after setPassword. if it does - you'd just query WHERE LastPasswordChangeDate != TODAY LIMIT 150 :)

What I am thinking is:
For the first 1800, I should use query with "ORDER BY Id ASC".
For the last 1200, I will modify the query with "ORDER BY Id DESC" .
This way the queue will be in descending order. I will then set pwds for the top 1200, using OFFSET
